# How to merge XFA PDF forms with PDFBox

Tags: pdf, pdfbox, xfa

I have multiple PDFs in XFA format and are looking for ways to merge them into one PDF with PDFBox.  I tried to use

```
PDFMergerUtility.appendDocument(PDDocument destination, PDDocument source)
```

or

```
DFMergerUtility.addSource(InputStream source)
```

But both APIs fail to merge the PDFs.

Does PDFBox support the merge of dynamic forms? Can the XFA forms be flatten and then merged with PDFBox?

Comment: Merging XFA forms has to be done by working on the XFA xml streams. Pdfbox, though, mostly ignores these streams. So no, Pdfbox does not support merging XFA forms. Hardly any PDF library does. Neither does Pdfbox itself know how to 'flatten' XFA.

Comment: XFA files can not be merged with PDFs, because they are not really PDF (the PDF is a wrapper around the XML form allowing it to be displayed in Adobe's PDF viewers).